# Get Name of SubGrid on Account Form that Triggers Javascript on the Contact Quick Create Form OnLoad

Tags: javascript, controls, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

There is a subgrid on a account form that allows you to quick create a contact (contact quick create form).  OnLoad of the quick create form, I need to be able to identify what subgrid triggered the quick create form as there are many on the form.

I currently have the javascript as follows that triggers on the contact quick create form onLoad:

```
function contactQuickCreateFormOnLoad(context)
{
debugger;

//alert("hello world");

var formContext = context.getFormContext();

var control = formContext.getControl();

}
```

Am I approaching this correctly as I need to get perhaps the name of the subgrid that triggered the quick create form to load? Is this the correct scope?

I ask this because the above code seems to only allow me to see the actual controls on the quick create form. I can't locate any metadata pertaining to the subgrid that triggered this.

Any suggests would be great.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

- As far as I know, you do not get property from which subgrid your quick create form is opened, yes you do get from which parent entity your quick create is opened.
- What you could do is customize the button, Add a Js to open your quick create from and there in you can pass parameter.
- These parameter values you can  you can catch/get in your on load of quick create from

  ```
  var entityFormOptions = {};
   entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "contact";
   entityFormOptions["useQuickCreateForm"] = true;

   // Set default values for the Contact form
   var formParameters = {};
   formParameters["firstname"] = "Sample";
   formParameters["lastname"] = "Contact";
   formParameters["fullname"] = "Sample Contact";
   formParameters["emailaddress1"] = "contact@adventure-works.com";
   formParameters["jobtitle"] = "Sr. Marketing Manager";
   formParameters["donotemail"] = "1";
   formParameters["description"] = "Default values for this record were set programmatically.";

   // Set lookup column
   formParameters["preferredsystemuserid"] = "3493e403-fc0c-eb11-a813-002248e258e0"; // ID of the user.
   formParameters["preferredsystemuseridname"] = " Admin user"; // Name of the user.
   formParameters["preferredsystemuseridtype"] = "systemuser"; // Table name.
   // End of set lookup column

   // Open the form.
   Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, formParameters).then(
       function (success) {
           console.log(success);
       },
       function (error) {
           console.log(error);
       });
  ```

Comment: For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openform